# braincert whiteboard api problems

Tags: asp.net, api

I am new in APi.
I integrate braincert whiteboard in my project. According to braincert  documentation, i generate the API with domain.But the problem is when i use the code in project,there is an error
 You are accessing whiteboard from an unregistered domain.
I can't understand where i wrong 
this is my code below

```
<div id="wbplayer"> </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.braincert.com/whiteboard/braincert-wb.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        bcwb.init({
            apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxx', 
            height: '1500',
            width: '1500',
            bgcolor: '#FFF',
            logo: 'https://www.braincert.com/images/bc-logo-bottom.png'
        });
       </script>
```

Any one please help me.

Comment: Are you trying to access it from localhost?

Comment: no i am not using in localhost

Comment: Did you solved this ?